# is there any way to play the video in safari browser

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

below are 2 video files uploaded in aws. it will play in chrome or firefox etc, but wont play in safari

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/apppreprod/Vid_637768063547139404.webm
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/apppreprod/Vid_637745132425435217.mp4

The issue is that safari wont play videos uploaded into blob storage like aws.
recomended solution is to save the video in other server and it will play in safari.

Answer (score 0):

The two links you provide can be opened in other browsers. I tested it with an iPhone, and found that it could not be opened in the safari browser, but the other three-party iPhone browsers can. After checking the Apple official website, it is certain that the safari browser of the iPhone supports the MOV video format.

**suggestion:**

When uploading a video, the video can be converted and stored as needed

Comment: Is there any common video format that supports all the browsers and also it can be uploaded into blob storage like aws